# Iterate through result until 0 javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, math, iteration

I have written a javascript function which accepts a number of variables to produce a result what I need to do is produce a result which is 0.00 (+/- 0.01) by adjusting a percentage value that is passed to the function.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jerswell/33vyvm6n/

If you select the first item from the list you will see the table updates with results and from there a user can enter a value into the `Price ($)` field say `100` click calculate and the results panel will show the results of the calculation.

The YTM when selected is `4.371` which produces a result of a `Price ($)` = `8.52`

What I need to achieve is to show a result of `0.00 (+/- 0.01)` by iterating through the YTM value and decrementing or incrementing by 0.001 until this result is achieved, for this example a YTM of `6.002` gets us close enough as we are happy with a  `+/- 0.01` variation in the output.

On line `114` of the fiddle there is an if statement that I have started but I am now stuck as where to go from here.

```
    if (bondCalculation.calculatedPrice !== 0) {

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Binary search will work. The idea is to start with a low YTM value of 0 and a high value of, say, 12000. Then you take the average of the low and high values, look at the error, and adjust the low or high end accordingly. Keep doing this until the error is sufficiently small.

You can replace

```js
    if(bondCalculation.calculatedPrice !== 0) {

    }
```

with

```js
    function getPrice(ytm) {
        return bondCalc(bond_term, bond_coupons, bond_semi_function, ytm, bondFaceValue, xtbPrice).calculatedPrice;
    }
    var low = 0, high = 12000, ytm;
    var count = 0;
    while (true) {
        count += 1;
        if (count == 100) {
            break;
        }
        ytm = (low+high)/2;
        if (Math.abs(getPrice(ytm)) < 0.0001) {
            break;
        } else if (getPrice(ytm) > 0) {
            low = ytm;
        } else {
            high = ytm;
        }
    }
    ytm = Math.round(1000*ytm)/1000;
    yieldToMaturity.val(ytm);
    bond_indicative_yield = ytm;
    bondCalculation = bondCalc(bond_term, bond_coupons, bond_semi_function, bond_indicative_yield, bondFaceValue, xtbPrice);
```

to obtain this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yow44mzm/

Comment: Perfect! thanks so much really elegant solution to the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this, adjust variables/params as required:

```
if(calculatedPrice !== 0){
   var currentPrice = calculatedPrice;
   var adjustedYTM =  ytm + 0.01;
   calculatedPrice = calculatePrice(ytm, other, params);

   if(calculatedPrice > currentPrice)
       adjustedYTM = decrementYTM(ytm);
   else
       adjustedYTM = incrementYTM(ytm);

    ytm = adjustedYTM;
}

function incrementYTM(ytm){
    while(calculatedPrice > 0){
        ytm += 0.01;
        calculatedPrice = calculatePrice(ytm, other, params);
    }
    return ytm;
}

function decrementYTM(ytm){
    while(calculatedPrice > 0){
        ytm -= 0.01;
        calculatedPrice = calculatePrice(ytm, other, params);
    }
    return ytm;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer can you look at the Javascript in the fiddle and adjust it to reflect my code so that I am clear about this.